# How do I get transactions that contains the same items from another table using BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I have a BigQuery table containing a list of items, bundled together like this:

| Bundle Name | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| Bundle 1 | Apple |
| Bundle 1 | Watermelon |
| Bundle 2 | Grapes |
| Bundle 2 | Lemon |

Then, I also have a BigQuery table containing a list of transactions, where a transaction can contain more than one product, like this:

| Transactions ID | Product Name |
| --- | --- |
| Transactions 1 | Apple |
| Transactions 1 | Watermelon |
| Transactions 2 | Grapes |
| Transactions 2 | Lemon |
| Transactions 2 | Banana |
| Transactions 3 | Pineapple |
| Transactions 3 | Kiwi |
| Transactions 3 | Grapes |

I would like to get transactions that contain the exact item from the list of bundles. In this case, I should get Transaction 1 since it has a product combination in a transaction that exactly matches Bundle 1 (Apple and Watermelon) and Transactions 2 because it also has a product combination that matches Bundle 2 (Grapes and Lemon).

I can't use JOIN because if I join the Bundle table and Transaction table using Product Name, Transaction 3 will also be included since it has the same product name as Bundle 2 (Grapes).

How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select transactionID, bundleName
from (
  select transactionID, array_agg(distinct productName) as products
  from transactions group by transactionID
) t1, (
  select bundleName, array_agg(distinct productName) as products
  from bundles group by bundleName
) t2
where (
  select count(product1) = count(product2)
  from t2.products product2
  left join t1.products product1
  on product1 = product2 
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is works really well. Thank you Mikhail!